# How to display current username as a Link in RUBY?

Tags: ruby, link-to-function

```
<%= link_to ' ', user_path(current_user) %>
```

How do I make it so `<% current user %>` displays the current user as a link.
Because in ruby whatever goes inside Link to is written as a string and not displayed as Ruby's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code replace name with field that stores user's name

```
<%= link_to current_user.name, user_path(current_user) %>
```

Comment: Thanks. That works! I'd been putting    <% current user %>   all along *facepalm"